# touchpad multi-touch opens unity menu

Tags: touchpad, multi-touch, synaptics

I have an old Dell XPS 15 laptop running Ubuntu 16.04.3. I've always been experiencing annoying touchpad gesture behavior, for example when I try to scroll (2 fingers) and I touch the bottom of the touchpad, my unity menu always opens and then it activates whatever icon is under the cursor.

I'd like to disable it but I have no idea how to. I've searched through some other people's questions but could not find an answer for it.

Here is my (default) synclient configuration:

```
$ synclient 
Parameter settings:
    LeftEdge                = 64
    RightEdge               = 1536
    TopEdge                 = 48
    BottomEdge              = 852
    FingerLow               = 25
    FingerHigh              = 30
    MaxTapTime              = 180
    MaxTapMove              = 80
    MaxDoubleTapTime        = 100
    SingleTapTimeout        = 180
    ClickTime               = 100
    EmulateMidButtonTime    = 75
    EmulateTwoFingerMinZ    = 282
    EmulateTwoFingerMinW    = 112
    VertScrollDelta         = 36
    HorizScrollDelta        = 36
    VertEdgeScroll          = 0
    HorizEdgeScroll         = 0
    CornerCoasting          = 0
    VertTwoFingerScroll     = 1
    HorizTwoFingerScroll    = 1
    MinSpeed                = 1
    MaxSpeed                = 1.75
    AccelFactor             = 0.108992
    TouchpadOff             = 2
    LockedDrags             = 0
    LockedDragTimeout       = 5000
    RTCornerButton          = 2
    RBCornerButton          = 3
    LTCornerButton          = 0
    LBCornerButton          = 0
    TapButton1              = 1
    TapButton2              = 3
    TapButton3              = 0
    ClickFinger1            = 1
    ClickFinger2            = 1
    ClickFinger3            = 0
    CircularScrolling       = 0
    CircScrollDelta         = 0.1
    CircScrollTrigger       = 0
    CircularPad             = 0
    PalmDetect              = 0
    PalmMinWidth            = 160
    PalmMinZ                = 200
    CoastingSpeed           = 20
    CoastingFriction        = 50
    PressureMotionMinZ      = 30
    PressureMotionMaxZ      = 160
    PressureMotionMinFactor = 1
    PressureMotionMaxFactor = 1
    ResolutionDetect        = 1
    GrabEventDevice         = 0
    TapAndDragGesture       = 1
    AreaLeftEdge            = 0
    AreaRightEdge           = 0
    AreaTopEdge             = 0
    AreaBottomEdge          = 0
    HorizHysteresis         = 9
    VertHysteresis          = 9
    ClickPad                = 0
```

Not sure if it matters, but I only have this issue when I scroll up and start my fingers at the bottom edge of the touchpad.

Comment: can you tell us please what you tried already ? Looking through askubuntu and other sites the seems to be a lot of Dell XPS touchpad related issues like [these](https://askubuntu.com/a/894571/783023)

Comment: Do you have similar problems on different desktop environments?

Comment: I looked on askubuntu and saw a couple similar problems indicating it should be solved with synclient clickfinger options. I tried different values for all ClickFinger1 to 3 without any effect.
The solution was for a ubuntu 14 but I don't see how that's going to make a big difference.

Comment: @RobertRiedl Thanks for that link. The 'apt install xserver-xorg-input-libinput' did the trick, but now I lost the tap-to-click function.

Comment: oh god this sounds like a nightmare ! Can I suggest doing a clean install of 17.10, the most current release ?

Comment: Now if I tap with 2 fingers (only at the very bottom of the touchpad), I still get the context menu. It used to do this before as well. Scrolling from that same place used to open the Unity menu but that has now disappeared.

Comment: @RobertRiedl maybe that would resolve the issue, but I don't think I'll be doing that... I'd like to know how to solve a problem and not treat Linux the same as Windows.

Comment: Have you looked in the preferences for the Mouse options ? maybe with `libinput` there are different options or toggles ?

Comment: @NonnyMoose No, only Unity menu opens this way. If I use Gnome (compiz),  there was no issue.

Comment: @RobertRiedl libinput settings are very restricted. Primary mouse button (left or right) and double-click speed.

Comment: wait did you just say you only have these issues in Unity and not in Gnome ? Also, I was just trying to point out that 16.04 is kind of old (i.e. last change to libinput was April 2016, while it was March 2017 in artful). I'm with you with resolving problems but you seem to have suffered enough, unless you only installed 16.04 recently.

Comment: No I've been happily using 16.04 (I only use LTS versions) since it came out. And yes, it's only a Unity problem, not in Gnome. I've rolled back the libinput so I can tap again and just wait for another solution that doesn't introduce more problems :)

Comment: @Jakke What do you mean by "Unity Menu"? When I two finger scroll on this web page the only menu I can bring up is a browser based context menu. Do your touchpad left and right buttons work normally? Has this problem always been there or just started recently?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix like pressing the win/super key.  It only happens if I scroll from the bottom edge up. Yes, my mouse buttons otherwise work as normal.